# How to count the total number of duplicated chars in a string using nested loop?

Tags: java, string

I need to write a program that counts the total number of repeated characters in a String. For example, if the string is "gigi the gato", the output is 7. ('g' repeats 3 times + 'i' repeats 2 times + 't' repeats two times.) I need to use nested loop.

Here is what I have. The idea is correct but my output 5 is wrong.

```
public class CountD {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1 = "gigi the gato";
        s1 = s1.replace(" ", "");
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < s1.length(); j++) {
                if (s1.charAt(i) == s1.charAt(j)) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

The problem is that this code counts how many times each char repeats (if it does so) but it does not include char itself. And secondly, if char repeats more than two times, it counts this char extra times after each appearance. Sorry, if it's confusing. Anyway, you can trace the code by yourself. Can you fix it and explain how you did it, please?

Comment: Using two counter is allowed? If it is, use another counter to count current character and if the counter is greater than 1 then add that to the main counter. Do not forget to remove counted characters.

Answer (score 1):

Iterating through the same string with the outer `for` loop, will count the same char that was already counted again and again. 
Replace the outer `for` loop with a `while` loop and after each char checking, remove the char from the string:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s1 = "gigi the gato";
    s1 = s1.replace(" ", "");
    int count = 0;
    while (!s1.isEmpty()) {
        boolean found = false;
        for (int j = 1; j < s1.length(); j++) {
            if (s1.charAt(0) == s1.charAt(j)) {
                found = true;
                count++;
            }
        }
        if (found)
            count++;
        s1 = s1.replace(s1.substring(0, 1), "");
    }
    System.out.println(count);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a flag when there is a match. Once inner loop completes, based on the flag increase count. This ensures the inclusion of original char in count.

Answer (score 0):

Is it really necessary to have a nested loop? You could try this instead:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String s1 = "gigi the gato";
  s1 = s1.replaceAll(" ", "");
  int count = 0;
  while (s1.length() > 0) {
    int lengthBefore = s1.length();
    String firstChar = s1.substring(0, 1);
    s1 = s1.replace(firstChar, "");
    int diff = lengthBefore - s1.length();
    if (diff > 1) count += diff;
  }
  System.out.println(count);
}
```

Comment: From the OP's question: *I need to use nested loop*

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int countDuplicatedChars(String str) {
    int count = 0;
    char[] arr = str.toLowerCase().toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        char ch = arr[i];

        if (ch == ' ' || ch == '\0')
            continue;

        int total = 0;

        for (int j = i; j < arr.length; j++) {
            if (ch != arr[j])
                continue;
            total++;
            arr[j] = '\0';
        }

        if (total > 1)
            count += total;
    }

    return count;
}
```

You can do the same with `Stream`:

```
public static int countDuplicatedChars(String str) {
    return str.chars()
              .filter(ch -> ch != ' ')
              .mapToObj(i -> (char)i)
              .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.counting(), Long::intValue)))
              .entrySet().stream()
              .mapToInt(Map.Entry::getValue)
              .filter(count -> count > 1)
              .sum();
}
```

Comment: Good example of Stream API usage. However, adding some explanation will help a lot for understanding.

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to use streaming:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.counting;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;

public static long countD(String s) {
    Map<Integer, Long> map = s.chars()
            .filter(c -> c != ' ').boxed()
            .collect(groupingBy(c -> c, counting()));

    return map.values().stream()
            .filter(count -> count > 1)
            .mapToLong(c -> c)
            .sum();
}


  public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.err.println(countD("gigi the gato")); // 7
        System.err.println(countD("gigi tge gato")); // 8
  }
```